# error installing xampp 1.8.1 in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: xampp

`sudo apt-get install xampp`
 after above step the following error is shown

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xampp:i386 : Depends: python-gtk2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-glade2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Question: xamp is NOT part of Ubuntu so why does your apt-get work? This is how to install Xamp: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html but I would strongly suggest to use the native LAMP stack. It is far more secure and a lot less hassle to get working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message.

Try this link:

http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-xampp-in-ubuntu.html

I downloaded version 1.8.1 from this link:

http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz

Worked perfect for me.

Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

maybe ubuntu repo does not come with xampp, you can download xampp from source and install xampp

```
# wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run
# chmod 755 xampp-linux*
./xampp-linux*
```